# maybe you just know what makes the asterisks on this loop so much

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
    var s = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            s += '*'
        }
        s += '\n';
        console.log(s)
    }




    maybe you just know what makes the asterisks on this loop so much?
```

even though I only want to repeat it for 5 lines, but why are there so many results?

```
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zzOu.png
```

Comment: You are creating five lines of ten stars. Yet you log it after each additional line (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) which may seem like you have more stars. Change `console.log(s)` to `console.log(i, s)` for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is producing the following result:

[image: Code from Question]

Because not resetting the var `s` inside the outter iteration.

Instead, you may do:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  let s = '';
  for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    s += '*';
  }
  s += '\n';
  console.log(s);
}
```

which will produce the expected result.